# How remove parts of a value in each value of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
original_list = ['1 b Victor','1 b Pedro','1 b Laura','1 b Maria']
```

I want to remove "1 b" from each value of the list and reach this example list:

```
final_result = ['Victor', 'Pedro', 'Laura', 'Maria']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That's not a valid Python list.

Comment: You example code is full of syntax errors. But in general, think about how to solve the *single* case first. E.g. by slicing off the first 4 characters. The pattern for "doing something to all elements of a list" can be a standard list comprehension; `final_result = [name[4:] for name in names]`

Comment: I fixed the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `str.replace()` in a list comprehension.

```
final_result = [s.replace('1 b ', '') for s in original_list]
```

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it.